# Laravel eloquent orderBy a date field not returning all values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

If I use

`$users = User::orderBy('last_modified', 'DESC')->get();`

I don't get all the users.

However if I use

`$users = User::all();`

I get all the users.

The last_modified values in the DB are the same type everybody, a timestamp holding values such as year-month-day 00:00:00

Is that a known Laravel/eloquent issue? Not sure how to debug this... I'm thinking about just getting all the items and then sorting it by the date with PHP...

I return the data with return View::make('dashboard')->with and then use it in the front end with a loop.

All the data is displayed as I want it in the HTML.

Before the loop, the array count is 86. After it, it's still 86 (I did that just to make sure nothing in the loop changed the array).

Then, when console logging the same data used in the loop, data is missing.

```
var appUsers = {{ json_encode($users); }};
console.log(appUsers);
```

I also tried console logging at the start of the HTML document and same issue.

When I don't sort by last_modified, no data is missing.

Comment: Strange... Is there something special about the records that are ignored? Do you recognize any pattern?

Comment: When doing dd() (after fetching all without sorting), the last modified looks something like:  `'last_modified' => string '2015-02-12 10:23:50' (length=19)` for any row -- whether it's removed or kept after the sorting.

Comment: And the count() (or length when doing it on the front-end for the same array)  is the right total -- even though the array only really is not showing all the fields.

Comment: So where exactly are users missing? Can you edit the question and add more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Robert - What does `dd(User::orderBy('last_modified', 'DESC')->get());` return on the screen? Is it just an empty collection? I just tried this and I am able to get users sorted by `last_modified`.

Is it possible you have a typo in your field name in the DB?

Also, do all your users have "00:00:00" at the end of their timestamp? Because users in my system have actual time filled out there.

*(I would have asked these questions as comments but don't have enough reputation yet.)*

Comment: All the last_modified fields are something like `2015-02-11 23:57:03`

Comment: It's weird because when I dd and count(), the number is right, counted all the items in the DB

Comment: ok there seems to be corrupted last_modified values, although I don't see it in the DB. Even after if I sort the dates via PHP, some data is missing.

Comment: What does `dd(User::orderBy('last_modified', 'DESC')->get());` return on the screen?

Comment: It correctly returns all the fields, I used pre tags to show more clearly and they are really all there and the data seems right for all the last_modified values.

Comment: One more thought would be to check if you have `last_modified` in the dates array on your User model. `protected $dates = ['last_modified'];`

Comment: I added protected $dates = ['last_modified']; to the Model and I'm still getting the same issue. I added more info in my post.

Comment: i can screen share you, there are not many steps taken, i dont see which step transforms my data... skype?